# Replace values in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
     site1  site2   site3   site4   site5   site6   site7   site8   site9   site10
session_id                                      
21669   56  55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
54843   56  55  56  55  0   0   0   0   0   0
77292   946 946 951 946 946 945 948 784 949 946
114021  945 948 949 948 945 946 947 945 946 946
146670  947 950 948 947 950 952 946 951 946 947
```

And I have json with

```
{u'i1-js-14-3-01-11544-644949368-i.init.cedexis-radar.net': 13852,
 u'static.vol24.fr': 6240,
 u'mars.nasa.gov': 39840,
 u'scholar.google.fr': 3899,
 u'9zouxfza1h.s.ad6media.fr': 9677,
 u'afecaa4b0c028e55502bc297410239d4d.profile.mad50.cloudfront.net': 34973,
 u'www.decoration-stickers.com': 950,
 u'www.aldaniti.net': 56,
 u'cc.bingj.com': 55,
 u'www.bwin.fr': 6824,
...}
```

I try to replace values in dataframe with

```
site_dict_upd = {y:x for x,y in site_dict.iteritems()}
full_sites_names = pd.DataFrame()
full_sites_names = [full_sites[col].map(site_dict) for col in sites]
```

But it returns all NaN values.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try `df.replace`? `full_sites = full_sites.replace(site_dict_upd)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use `applymap`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: site_dict_upd[x] if x in site_dict_upd else x)
```

**EDIT**

Or as [coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) suggested:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: site_dict_upd.get(x, x))
```

Comment: Would be simpler to call `get` here:  `df.applymap(lambda x: site_dict_upd.get(x, x))`

Comment: It would, absolutely forgot about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.replace` method:

```
full_sites_names.replace(site_dict_upd, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Seeing as _you_ posted first, I don't see why _you_ don't deserve a +1 too, so, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), if no replacing maybe is necessary convert values to same `types`:

```
site_dict_upd = {y:x for x,y in site_dict.items()}
#convert to same types if necessary (int)
df = full_sites_names.astype(int).replace(site_dict_upd)
print (df)
                       site1                        site2             site3  \
session_id                                                                    
21669       www.aldaniti.net                 cc.bingj.com                 0   
54843       www.aldaniti.net                 cc.bingj.com  www.aldaniti.net   
77292                    946                          946               951   
114021                   945                          948               949   
146670                   947  www.decoration-stickers.com               948   

                   site4                        site5  site6  site7  site8  \
session_id                                                                   
21669                  0                            0      0      0      0   
54843       cc.bingj.com                            0      0      0      0   
77292                946                          946    945    948    784   
114021               948                          945    946    947    945   
146670               947  www.decoration-stickers.com    952    946    951   

            site9  site10  
session_id                 
21669           0       0  
54843           0       0  
77292         949     946  
114021        946     946  
146670        946     947
```

Comment: I can't check this, because my cpu can't execute that, it returns me kernel error

Comment: `kernel error ` ? Too large data? Or maybe help restart PC :(

Comment: thar's strange, but restart PC didn't help